# Photons are packets of electromagnetic radiation (wave) what about other particles?

Tags: waves

Photons are packets of electromagnetic radiation (wave), what about other particles? Are other particles, say electrons, really just packets of waves?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is the wave-particle duality a real duality?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/46237/)

Comment: One might take the view that, in the same way photons can be considered packets of EM radiation, electrons are packets of [beta radiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_particle). I doubt that anyone thinks in these terms, but I think the analogy holds.

Comment: I don't think "photons are packets of EM wave" is an accurate statement.  As to what physical particles, i.e. those with rest mass, are made of, that's dang close to pure philosophy :-).   I prefer to stick with particles being the antithesis of the Infinite Improbability Drive.