# Particle position and speed

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-interpretations, wave-particle-duality

If I understand correctly, particle is something at a point of time, where you can tell it's position, but what if particle is moving, then you can tell it's speed.

From what I understand wave is NOT particle moving, but rather, a phase the particle is in. The particle was agitated and turned into a wave.

So, what do you call a moving particle if it's not a wave? Could the particle's movement be represented as a wave because particle has tendencies to be at certain places at certain times?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is the wave-particle duality a real duality?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/46237/)

Comment: Woah, this is one confused question. The wave in question is a probability amplitude. It has nothing to do with the momentum of the particle being zero or non-zero.

Comment: There are neither waves or particles in quantum mechanics, hence all these questions lead to nothing.

Comment: @Dimensio1n0 That comment helps. I'm trying to get my head around these concepts. They are interesting, but very challenging.

Answer (score 1):

Waves have a speed as well, and it satisfies the wave equation $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} =  c^2 \nabla^2$ where is $c$ is the speed of the wave.

You said

> "The particle was agitated and turned into a wave"

If you mean this context the wave-particle duality, actually if we don't agitate the particle (collapse it's wave fuction) it's wave function, which satisfies the wave equation if we know it's momentum it has no definite **position** likewise if we know it's position it has no **definite** momentum this does not imply that value of the position or momentum is zero rather it is not definite and possible values values have a probability associated with them which you can calculate if you know the wave function $\psi$ for position $x$ via $\langle \psi | x | \psi \rangle$  and similarly for momentum $p$ we $\langle \psi | p | \psi \rangle$