# Are all elementary particles exhibit wave-particle duality?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wave-particle-duality

I have watched a lot of videos about quantum theory/mechanics and other and when they speak, say, about double slit experiment they say that 'if you shoot an electron...'. Then I read somewhere that photon exhibits w-p duality. And on some other video the narrator said that all elementary particles can behave as a wave and a particle. So if it is true, it means that you can actually shoot a neutron or a proton or a photon in the double slit experiment and it will be the same?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/46237/50583

Comment: As the link above probably explains, EVERYTHING exhibits wave-particle duality. It's just that it is unnoticeable on human scales.

Comment: Getting there with large molecules https://medium.com/the-physics-arxiv-blog/physicists-smash-record-for-wave-particle-duality-462c39db8e7b  but this is a gee-whiz kinda blog.

Comment: Actually we should stop using the terminology wave-particle duality at once. There is no such thing. There is quantum mechanics (or QFT, or whatever else you want) and that's it.

Comment: The idea of wave-particle duality is a way for us to think about QM in a classical context