# Wave-particle duality for Higgs boson

Tags: particle-physics, higgs, wave-particle-duality, bosons

I know that all matter particles have a dual nature, particle and wave. And apart from matter, photons also have dual nature. But what about bosons, specifically Higgs bosons? Do they show both wave and particle characters?

Comment: Note: a photon is also a boson

Comment: Welcome to PhysicsSE! The concept of wave-particle duality is wrong: particles behave as particles. If your question is "does the Higgs boson behave in a similar manner?" then the answer is yes. On wave-particle duality, I can recommend https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/46303/220004 this answer and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=citY6G8ePJw this Feynman video.

Comment: If you are asking about interference effects of the Higgs, none such explored yet. But the Higgs is a cornerstone of Quantum Field Theory, which runs on this duality, as you put it…

Answer (score 0):

The Higgs boson has mass. According to the wave particle duality of nature, all particles have a wave nature. Therefore, the Higgs boson must also have a  wave particle duality.

This is true for all particles whether they are massive or not, or whether they are bosons or fermions.

Comment: Why specifying the massive nature of the Higgs, since the behavior asked by OP is (as you correctly said) independent of mass?