# Particle / wave based on an observation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wave-particle-duality

If light is a wave, why does it appear to behave like a particle when observed in the double slit?
Are we saying consciousness is definitely affecting reality?
Much appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the wave-particle duality a real duality?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/46237/)

Comment: [How can a red light photon be different from a blue light photon?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/540485/37364)